# how to refresh data to every 3 minutes in streamlit

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

I have written these function to show csv file data into UI of streamlit. That csv file is in 'w+' mode so data gets refreshed to every 3 minutes, want to display same on UI. Want to reflect data at same time on UI. That csv file data gets updated on time like 9:15, 9:18, 9:21AM.

```
def strike_details():
    col1, col2 = st.columns(2)
    with col1:
        st.header("NIFTY")
        data1 = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(directory_of_python_script, str('strike_data_csv') , "NIFTY_strike.csv"), on_bad_lines='skip')
        st.table(data1)

    with col2:
        st.header("BANKNIFTY")
        data2 = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(directory_of_python_script, str('strike_data_csv') , "BANKNIFTY_strike.csv"), on_bad_lines='skip')
        st.table(data2)

strike_details()
```

These function displays tables like below image
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the `schedule` module?.

```py
import time
import streamlit as st
from schedule import every, repeat, run_pending


with st.empty():
    @repeat(every(3).minutes)
    def strike_details():
        col1, col2 = st.columns(2)
        with col1:
            st.header("NIFTY")
            data1 = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(directory_of_python_script, str('strike_data_csv') , "NIFTY_strike.csv"), on_bad_lines='skip')
            st.table(data1)

        with col2:
            st.header("BANKNIFTY")
            data2 = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(directory_of_python_script, str('strike_data_csv') , "BANKNIFTY_strike.csv"), on_bad_lines='skip')
            st.table(data2)


    while True:
      run_pending()
      time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Yes I have tried with schedule module but I have multiple functions and at last as I applied scheduler for these function then it is not going to next function. Still will try your way for each function. I need to start scheduler from specific time and want to run only for weekdays in between 9:15AM to 3:30PM time.

Comment: Do all functions use the same csv files?.

Comment: I have created 2 functions in file and both reading different csv files

Comment: If that is the case, I think you can refactor the code by putting those functions to a separate python file and and schedule them to make the automation there by `only` updating the `csv `files. And in the other python file you `only` read the `csv` files. I am pretty sure that when the content of the `csv` files change, where you are reading them will automatically change as well.

Comment: Okay sure will try such way now

Comment: I resolved it by using st.autorefresh() function with 1 min time. It's rerun all streamlit script start to end so data gets refreshed. Thanks